# How to make views header sticky while scrolling?

Tags: views, theming

I have created report using drupal views and i used views_merge_rows module. Now i wanted to create sticky header of report table. Can any one please help me.

Comment: u have used tables rite ?? under format in views

Comment: i have used table rowspan instead of views default table format using views_merge_rows module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Under the format in views select table.
2. Got to settings on table there will find the checkbox named Enable Drupal style "sticky" table headers (Javascript) . Enable it
3. In views preview u can see the sticky headers of the table.